# AngularJS access object before and after selected object and render them in a new view

Tags: angularjs, json, ng-view

My app has two views, A library view and a book view. From the first view (library), the user selects an object and it loads the second view (book) with the selected objects data. From there I'd like to display the json object before and after the selected object. I'm struggling with how to load these ancillary objects data into the view. One idea I had was to create a service with an array of the previous item, selected item, and next item in it, however I only know how to load the selected item's data into the array from the library view.

Thoughts? even a point in the right direction would be incredibly helpful.

Thank you!

The library view:

```
<ul id="Library"> 
    <li class="bookend" ng-repeat="book in library" ng-click="open_book(book)"></li>
</ul>
```

and the Library controller:

```
$scope.open_book = function(book){
    var selected_book_path = '/books/' + book.id;
    $location.path(selected_book_path);
};
```

which loads the Book view:

```
<div id="Book">
   <h1 class="book-title">{{ book.title }}</h1>
   <h2 class="book-author">{{ book.author }}</h2>
   <h2 class="book-year">{{ book.year }}</h2>
</div>
```

Within the book view, I also want to load the data before and after the selected book.

Comment: you should post the code.